# first OpenGL program from the Red book crashes when it returns

Tags: c++, opengl

I read the "Red book"(OpenGL Programming Guide) and tried the first program in the book under windows 7 with VS2010.

The result can appear normally, but when the program returns, it crashes with the following information:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x6992c660 in first.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
```

I have tried some other programs, which issued the same problem.

The following is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>

void display(void)
{
/* clear all pixels */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

/*  draw white polygon (rectangle) with corners at
 *  (0.25, 0.25, 0.0) and (0.75, 0.75, 0.0)
 */
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(0.25, 0.25, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.75, 0.25, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.75, 0.75, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.25, 0.75, 0.0);
    glEnd();

/*  don't wait!
 *  start processing buffered OpenGL routines
 */
    glFlush();
}

void init(void)
{
/*  select clearing (background) color  */
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

/* initialize viewing values */
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}

/*
 *  Declare initial window size, position, and display mode
 *  (single buffer and RGBA). Open window with "hello"
 *  in its title bar. Call initialization routines.
 *  Register callback function to display graphics.
 *  Enter main loop and process events.
 */

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(250, 250);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("hello");
    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FWIW that's *very* outdated OpenGL - fixed pipline functionality is deprecated

Comment: I tested this under ubuntu 11.10: g++ test.cpp -lGL -lglut.  Program ran without error.

Comment: Check whether you have correct (and not corrupt) glut library. Also as mentioned, don't use fixed function.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Where does it stop?

Comment: It shall never reach `return 0;` before you close glut window. Set break point and `glutMainLoop();` and step into it.

Comment: I have basically the same error